# factorial function running error : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, factorial

I have made a calculator using javascript . I want to add factorial to it but chrome said to me : Maximum call stack size exceeded.
these are some parts of code , I am sure the problem is these code not other

```
function fac(firstNum){
    firstNum=Number(document.getElementById('result').value);
    if(firstNum==0){
        document.getElementById('result').value = 1;
    }
    var a = firstNum*fac(firstNum-1);
    document.getElementById('result').value = a;
}
```

and using function into switch case

```
case 'n!':
    document.getElementById('result').value = fac();
break;
```

what's the problem ?

Comment: you don't return anything and you never use `firstNum` as it was given to you.

Comment: yep, you need return a value. Assumming that you are trying the recursive version of factorial.

Comment: however , what I have to do exactly ? give the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the factorial algorithm from the UI code.

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
}
```

And then use this code to retrieve the number from the UI field, say `factInput` and place the result field, say `factResult`:

```
var number = document.getElementById('factInput').value;
document.getElementById('factResult').value = factorial(number);
```

HTH,
Bryan